# How to make objdump show jumps in diff-friendly way

Tags: objdump

I'm struggling with understanding the jumps shown by `objdump`, taking into consideration that it should be `diff`-friendly.

**Use `--visualize-jumps`**

This is pretty nice and clear for the jumps. However, it works well only when looking at a single listing. If I have two listings (like before and after the change) and compare them with `diff`, the extra markers visualizing jumps break the diff view a lot.

**Use `--line-numbers`**

I'm not able to tell how would this work because it is in my case *so long* that I never waited long enough to see the results.

**Count by hand**

I'm seeing cases like:

```
ja <symbol+offset>
```

with the `offset` part being - I presume - hex offset in bytes from the start of the `symbol`.

So, I could *not use* `--no-addresses` and then each line starts with the address, subtracting the address of the first line I can see where the jump leads. However, this again breaks `diff` view since two builds may have different base addresses of the same symbol. (And even if they luckily wouldn't for larger changes this may still alter what `diff` shows.)

(For the record, I could also use `--show-raw-insn` and count bytes per line. But I'm afraid this would still break `diff` view in many cases while making the counting much more difficult.)

**What I would prefer**

If the `offset` part could be shown as a line number in the listing.

Or at least if I could rebase the symbol to a given address (preferably `0` of course) to mitigate different bases between different builds. (But I expect this would still mess with the `diff` view in case of larger differences.)

I guess the approach with no `--no-addresses` described above could be automated with a reasonable effort. But if so, maybe there is tooling that already does so. Or a set of switches to `objdump` that I just fail to see.